# Why does javascript subtract an entire month rather than one day if the time isn't zeroed out?

Tags: javascript, date

**Not looking for solutions, just want to know why I get those results and get a better understanding of javascript.**

I'm calculating dates and date strings for today through 3 days ago. If I zero out time for today, everything works just fine. If I don't (and maybe also it's close to midnight UTC) yesterday is a month ago, other previous day calculations work as expected.

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot of code run in the console with results]

Code run in the console at about 5:30p eastern which is 11:30p UTC

Here's the code so you can run it yourself.

Zero out time and yesterday is yesterday:

```
let today = new Date();
today.setUTCHours(0,0,0); // remove time, otherwise yesterday if based off of today could be a month ago.
let todays_date_string = today.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

let yesterday = new Date(todays_date_string);
yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
let yesterdays_date_string = yesterday.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

let two_days_ago = new Date(yesterdays_date_string);
two_days_ago.setDate(two_days_ago.getDate() - 1);
let two_days_ago_date_string = two_days_ago.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

let three_days_ago = new Date(two_days_ago_date_string);
three_days_ago.setDate(three_days_ago.getDate() - 1);
let three_days_ago_date_string = three_days_ago.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
console.log({today, today_s: today.toISOString(), todays_date_string, yesterdays_date_string, two_days_ago_date_string, three_days_ago_date_string});
```

Don't zero out time and yesterday is a month ago:

```
let today = new Date();
//today.setUTCHours(0,0,0); // remove time, otherwise yesterday if based off of today could be a month ago.
let todays_date_string = today.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

let yesterday = new Date(todays_date_string);
yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
let yesterdays_date_string = yesterday.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

let two_days_ago = new Date(yesterdays_date_string);
two_days_ago.setDate(two_days_ago.getDate() - 1);
let two_days_ago_date_string = two_days_ago.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

let three_days_ago = new Date(two_days_ago_date_string);
three_days_ago.setDate(three_days_ago.getDate() - 1);
let three_days_ago_date_string = three_days_ago.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
console.log({today, today_s: today.toISOString(), todays_date_string, yesterdays_date_string, two_days_ago_date_string, three_days_ago_date_string});
```

Also note that I'm using today to calculate yesterday's date rather than the newly created yesterday based off today's date string which could be a contributing factor. But I wouldn't think that would affect calculating yesterday and certainly not to that degree.

Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: @john-jones so, just recreate `Date`? Because that already stores the date as an Unix timestamp in milliseconds.

Comment: @CollinD even Moment.js says [not to use Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Comment: Hey Folks, I appreciate the feedback. Not interested in solutions as setting time to all zeros gets the the correct answer. I simply want to understand why I get those results.

Comment: @pilchard The question is - Why am I seeing those results? Not looking for a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point is this: [The setDate() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate#description) changes the day of the month of a given Date instance, **based on local time**.

Let's walk through some code.

```js
const date = new Date('2023-02-01T22:34:47.458Z');
const todayDateString = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10); // 2023-02-01
const todayDateDate = new Date(todayDateString);
```

The value of `todayDateDate.toISOString()` is `2023-02-01T00:00:00.000Z`

The value of `date.getDate()` is `1`.

The value of `todayDateDate.toString()` is `Tue Jan 31 2023 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)` (this will vary depending on your time zone).

The local date is January 31!

If you `setDate(0)`, it gives you the last day of the previous month, based on local time. Since the local time is in January, this means December 31 in local time, and will be January 1 UTC.

The exact results depend on your local time zone.

Comment: Thank you @Aurast - confirmed that's the issue.  I switched from `setDate()` to `setUTCDate()` and that made it work as intended!

Answer (score 0):

When you construct the new date that doesn't explicitly specify a time zone, e.g. `new Date('2023-02-01')`, the date is interpreted in your local time zone.

But when you stringify it via `toISOString()` you get the date in the UTC time zone, which could be a different day (the other side of midnight).

Consider:

```js
// February 1 in UTC+05:00
const d1 = new Date('2023-02-01T01:00:00+05:00')

// is still January 31 in UTC
console.log(d1.toISOString()); // 2023-01-31T20:00:00.000Z
```

So if

1. your timezone offset means it's still yesterday in UTC, and
2. yesterday was still January 31 instead of February 1, then
3. `setDate(1)` makes it January 1: a month ago.

Comment: You have the offset/interaction backwards

Comment: It can happen in either direction.

Comment: I believe UTC should always be ahead of or equal to your local timezone.

Comment: @evan no, if you're at a time zone which is +01:00, then the time zone is ahead of UTC by one hour. Roughly half the world is ahead of UTC. And almost half behind it. The UK are, for example, *at* UTC but only during the winter.

Comment: @VLAZ You are correct, I wasn't thinking that piece through. The output shows that the timezone is Eastern time and therefore behind UTC. So the timezone offset, in this case, means UTC is either today or tomorrow compared to local. UTC is not yesterday as this answer states.

Comment: Sorry--I get that this answer doesn't faithfully reproduce your exact issue. I was just trying to demonstrate that timezones and date construction/serialization can interact in ways that will cause the type of thing you're witnessing, specifically how it could produce a date that's off by a month.